# Does one want to play Taiwanese IMO team's game with more people or with less people?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, graph-theory

First one should read my this [Question about the Taiwanese IMO team's game](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1146363/what-is-the-probability-of-losing-in-the-taiwainese-imo-teams-game)

The expression of the losing probability in that post is fairly complicated (too complicated for me to handle, absorb or even to gain much information from it), and the answerers generously calculated the odds of the case $n=6$ which is slightly over than a half. It is trivial that if $n=2$ both players will lose the game, and that gives rise to my further curiosity: is the function $p(n)$, defined as the losing probability of a player in $n$ players' game, monotonically decreasing? Or is it more complicated? In particular, does it have a lower bound?

Answer (score 1):

We have \begin{align*} p(n) &=\frac{\sum_{k=2}^n(k-1)!{n-1\choose k-1}(n-1)^{n-k}}{(n-1)^n}\\&\leq \frac{(n-1)!e^{n-1}}{(n-1)^n}\\&\leq \frac{(n-1)^{n-\frac{1}{2}}e^{-(n-1)}e^{n-1}}{(n-1)^n} \\&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n-1}}.\end{align*}

(The second line comes from playing around a bit with definitions and the Taylor series for $e^x$, and the third line is roughly [Stirling's approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation).)

Since $p(n)\geq 0$ we see that $\lim_{n\to\infty} p(n)= 0$.

(I would be shocked if $p(n)$ is not also monotonically decreasing, but to be honest I haven't checked.)

Comment: At least we see it has no lower bounds and tends to zero.